# What R-packages for SOCP problems are there?

Tags: r, optimization, numerical-methods, software, portfolio-optimization

Currently, I am looking deeper into the topic of [second-order cone programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-order_cone_programming).

**Could you suggest packages that solve SOCP-problems in R?**

With your answer, please provide a **short description** of the approach the solver takes to arrive at the solution. The software should be *non-commerial* and ideally either on *CRAN or R-forge*.

Comment: There's at least one in the [Optimization Task View](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html). You can probably find more [by searching via rseek](http://www.rseek.org/?cx=010923144343702598753%3Aboaz1reyxd4&q=second-order+cone+programming&newwindow=1&cof=FORID%3A11). I'm not sure if it's the same here, but questions asking to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic on StackOverflow.

Comment: I wouldn't use an optimizer in R. If this is just for playing try dwd. But if this is something serious and money is involved. I highly recommend you use mosek.

Comment: @WilmerEHenaoH Why not? My problems are neither time-critical nor large scale...